# Multiple .bashrc profiles

Tags: bash, terminal

Is there a way to switch between multiple .bashrc files and reload bash?
I want to have two different sets of environment variables and switch between them. Preferably in a terminal emulator and/or with a keystroke.

Comment: Why not having `.bashrc` and `.bashrc_bkp` or something like that?

Comment: Sure, i'll do that. But how to i switch between them?

Comment: `source .bashrc`?

Comment: You can't really "switch", because there's no way to really undo what was in the former file. You can simply source the new one, but that won't be the same as starting a new shell with the new one.

Comment: Why does it need to be a single Shell? Why not simply run multiple shells with different settings, then `suspend` when you want to go back to the top Shell to switch to another active Shell? Or just use multiple tabs in your terminal emulator?

Answer (score 3):

Create different .bashrc files or any files which has your environment variables or even other data which you want in them, for example you can have three .bashrc files at your home directory.

1. `/home/user/.bashrc1`. -- this file has one version of your env variables.
2. `/home/user/.bashrc2`. -- this file has another version of your environment variables.
3. `/home/user/.bashrc`. -- this file has the main environment variables which will be automatically called when bash shell is started up.

edit this file `/home/user/.bashrc` and make entries as below

`alias env1='/home/user/.bashrc1'`

`alias env2='/home/user/.bashrc2'`

Now execute command `. $HOME/.bashrc`

When you want env1 variables to be available in shell type env1 and to switch to env2 variables to be available in shell type env2

This is one way you could switch between two different environment variables

Comment: This doesn't switch; it just overlays one set of changes over the previous one.

Comment: It may not switch bu, this can be made to unset other environment variables in the new profile. which may solve the purpose.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `env1(){ . ~/.bashrc1; }` or `alias env1=". ~/.bashrc1"` and a corresponding version for env2? (The missing `.` means it won't work usefully.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch from one bashrc to another while you are in one terminal, you can follow [Eby Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50230932/5825294), but be aware that, as commented by @chepner, that this will not undo what the "main" `~/.bashrc` has done.

If you want to switch select one of several `.bashrc`s **before** opening a terminal, then maybe you can have the `~/.bashrc` file be a symbolic link to one of `.bashrc1`, `.bashrc2`, ..., and when you want to change, you simply reassign the link by `ln -sf .myWinterBashrc ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can have a look to a tool I wrote in pure-bash to manage multiple profiles. It will give you a function named `switch_profile` that will load function/aliases/export from multiple files. It also supports unloading the settings you have into a profile before loading another one so you can be sure that a particular setting (e.g. an export of a variable that may affect other programs behavior) will be cleared between switches.
You can find it [here](https://github.com/gianluca-mascolo/bash-profile-switcher) I hope it will be useful.